# What is a stylistically preferred structure for lots of if statements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a code that needs to conditionally plot up to 6 plots as requested by the user.

The user can specify a character vector like '123', '245', '123456', '3456', etc. If the figure number is in the character vector, the plot needs to be made. If it doesn't appear in the character vector the plot doesn't get made.

The only logic I can think to do is:

```
str = '123456'; 

if contains(str,'1')
    % plot 1
end

if contains(str,'2')
    % plot 2
end

if contains(str,'3')
    $ plot 3
end

% etc... for a total of six if statements
```

Is there a better way to instantiate this logic in code? I cannot `switch` or `elseif` because generically more than 1 of the plots needs to be made.

**Edit:** I am unable to use a for loop solution

```
for i = 1:6
    if contains(str,i)
        % plot i
    end
end
```

because within `% plot i`, I would have to do the same set of 6 if statements to determine what to pass to the plot command.

Comment: Note: I made need/choose to have even more than 6 plots.

Comment: Are there similarities in the code for the various plots?

Comment: Some, but none that I think are leverageable. If I did a for loop and a conditional statement for whether the ith plot should be made, I would have to then perform if statements to determine what to pass into the plot command and how to format the plot.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the sequence of `if` statements is just fine. It's efficient and easy to implement. If you want your users to be able to change the order of plots as well, by giving the `str` in different orders, you'll have to use a `for` loop with a `switch` statement:

```matlab
for c = str
  switch c
    case '1'
      % plot 1
    case '2'
      % plot 2
    % ...
  end
end
```

A slightly more complex solution that avoids code replication could be as follows:

```matlab
plotdata(1).x = 1:100;
plotdata(1).y = randn(100,1);
plotdata(1).format = {'linewidth',2,'marker','o','color','m'};
plotdata(1).title = 'series 1';

plotdata(2).x = ...

for c = str
  indx = c - '0';
  figure
  plot(plotdata(indx).x,plotdata(indx).y,plotdata(indx).format{:});
  title(plotdata(indx).title);
  % maybe more formatting commands here
end
```

If each plot uses a different command, you could put anonymous functions into your data structure as follows:

```matlab
plotdata(1).cmd = @()plot(1:100,randn(100,1),'linewidth',2,'marker','o','color','m');
plotdata(1).title = 'series 1';

%...

figure
plotdata(indx).cmd();
title(plotdata(indx).title);
```